# how to move cursor directly to the next new line?

Tags: vim

here is my article.

```
with a screen editor,you can scroll the 
page,move the cursor,delete lines,insert
```

my cursor position is at the beginning of the second line (character 'p' of  "page"):

I want to continue my edit, so i press the `esc` key to reenter command mode, and then press '$' to move to the end of this line.

I then press the 'enter' key, so that i may continue my edit... Is there a simpler way to do this ?

Comment: For what it's worth; (I notice from editing some of your previous questions also), commas come before the space.

Comment: As pointed below, the question is unclear. If the question is "what's the fastest way to insert text at the end of a line while the cursor is at the beginning of it, then one way it's pressing shift+a in normal mode.

Comment: Why can't you just press `Right` and have the cursor appear at the start of the next line? Proposals in this page are madness.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This question is quite hard to understand, but i think you're either asking for how can you create a new line in command mode (use 'o') or how can you move down a line in vim ('j').

If it's neither of these things you wish to know, please say.

Answer (score 8):

The simplest way is probably hit `ctrl-o` then `$`.

`ctrl-o` puts you into command mode **for one command only**, so the `$` puts you to the end of the line, then you're automatically back into insert mode, and can continue your edit - i.e. hit enter an you're on the next line.

Comment: ah, yeah - if this is what's being asked by luofeiyu, hitting the 'end' key will also do it.

Answer (score 1):

Press ctrl + o, then $ sign. Now press Esc + i and finally hit enter and this will lead you to the next line.

Answer (score 1):

Press <kbd>end</kbd> key and then press <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>enter</kbd>.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to move the cursor directly to the next line (albeit without creating a new line and specifically from insert mode) is `ctrl-g j` or `ctrl-g ctrl-j`. See `:h ins-special-special` for more doubly special maneuvers.